# Lucene KNN token vectors demo

Tags: lucene, knn

I am trying to use a larger vector dictionary with the demo code. I have tried all the files here https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/ and every one throws this...

```
inputs are added out of order lastInput=[74 68 65] vs input=[2e]
java.lang.AssertionError: inputs are added out of order lastInput=[74 68 65] vs input=[2e]
    at org.apache.lucene.util.fst.FSTCompiler.add(FSTCompiler.java:478)
    at com.trevr.service.lucene.knn.KnnVectorDict$Builder.addOneLine(KnnVectorDict.java:222)
```

The "toy" one included in the demo works fine. Anybody getting this to work?
Thanks.